# TaskCompletionSource и System.Timers.Timer выполнить задачу не блокируя консольный ввод

Tags: c#, task

```
        public Task<int> AwaitCompletion()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        timer = new(10000)
        {
            AutoReset = true,           
        };

        timer.Start();

        timer.Elapsed += (s,e) => tcs.TrySetResult(0);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static async Task Main()
{
    TimerService timerService = new TimerService();

    var result = await timerService.TestAwait();

    Console.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Что я хочу получить:

По событию таймера выполнить:

```
 var result = await timerService.TestAwait();
```

и не ожидая его завершения перейти к:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

Сейчас после вызова TestAwait() консоль блокируеться на указанные в таймере интервал (10с) и только после этого выполняеться:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

Что я делаю не так и как это можно исправить?

Спасибо!

Comment: Чтобы не ожидать таск не пишите await, собственно

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите его ожидать, то await указывать стоит там, где вы его хотите ожидать, а в других случаях можно делать так:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    TimerService timerService = new TimerService();
    var Task1 = timerService.TestAwait(); // Таким образом он запускается в "параллельном режиме".
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
    // И когда нам понадобиться значение этого кода, мы начинаем ожидать выполнение метода
    var Result = await Task1; // кейвордом await, мы как бы говорим то что нужно подождать пока этот Task(задача, метод) выполниться.
}
```

Comment: Я наверное немного не правильно сформулировал мысль.
Я хочу что бы TestAwait() начал выполнять сразу, к примеру если вывести результат в консоль:
Console.WriteLine(await timerService.AwaitCompletion());
Console.WriteLine("Test");
Что бы сначала вывелся "Test",  а затем, после обработки задачи AwaitCompletion().
Т.е. что бы метод начал выполняться не блокируя основной поток и по завершению работы вывел результат

Comment: Тогда логичнее всего вам сделать вот так: Task.Factory.StartNew(AwaitCompletion).ContinueWith(async task =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(await task.Result);
            });
Console.WriteLine("Test");

Comment: Или так:
Task.Run(AwaitCompletion).ContinueWith(async task => { Console.WriteLine(await task); });
Console.WriteLine("Test");
Разница не существенная.